# Google chrome is always searching in local google domain instead of Google.com

Tags: google-chrome

I have changed in the search preferences to google.com but when I search from the address bar (instant or non-instant) it will still go to google.co.kr. Changing to "Google.com in English" does the same.

The only way is to open google.com first, then do the search in it.

So the question - is there any way to force Chrome to search in google.com instead of google.co.kr? I understand there is some geolocational checking/redirecting, but there must be some way to override it.

Comment: having the same problem and looking forward to find some answer on this thread in near future.

Comment: Actually there is a way, but you will not have instant search. Just create clone of default rule and replace `{google:baseURL}` with `google.com`.

Comment: Pablo - doing this prevents omnibox from returning "Instant" results though.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

- Have you marked the 'google.com' option as default?
- If not mark it as default using the 'make default' button (appears on hover).
- See the image below. It should be like that.

  [image]

Comment: Yes, it's marked as default

Comment: Okies.

Is it similar to above image? That means having 'google.com' as domain in all 3 columns.

Comment: Not exactly, because third column is non-editable. If I know what is correct search string template in order to make instant search also to work, then I could try to create new one maybe... But why `google:baseURL` is taking incorrect domain, I still don't get.

Comment: In that case you should add a new one with values same as in image and make it default.

Comment: `{google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:instantFieldTrialGroupParameter}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s` is default search string. How should I modify it to have instant searching working AND forcing to use `google.com` domain?

Comment: Make it ..

`http://www.google.com/search?q=%s`

Comment: This will cut off instant messaging!]

Comment: What instant messaging?

Comment: Sorry, instant searching (mobile autocorrection).

Comment: Adding a new search engine with above method won't stop instant searching, just remember to make it default.

Comment: Instant searching does NOT work with `http://www.google.com/search?q=%s`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is actually very simple.

When doing an omnibox search my desktop was returning google.co.uk, my laptop google.com so I knew something was up - and I really wanted the knowledge graph results from .com.

Follow all these steps in order.

1. Go to http://www.google.com. **If you're redirected to a country-specific site, click the "Go to Google.com" link in the bottom right of the Google home page.**
2. Do any search. This sets Google.com as your {google:baseURL} in a cookie.
3. Click the wrench icon and select "Exit" to fully exit Chrome.
4. Relaunch Chrome and try an Ombnibox search now.

This method will ensure that omnibox now returns results from at google.com *and* still searches instantly (if you have that option selected in your Chrome settings).

http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106514

Comment: I tried the above and the omnibox still searches the local google.

Comment: This worked for me! Quitting chrome and restarting just after the search was the crucial step.

Answer (score 3):

I created a new standard Search with the following settings:

Name: Google.com
Shortcut: google.com
and URL: 
https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}

and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Going to `http://google.com/ncr` disables the "country redirect" for me.

Comment: Again, if I open google.com from address bar there is no redirection! So it doesn't make sense to "Go to .../ncr". I tried to change search engine preferences and put /ncr but still Chrome is redirecting me to google.co.kr

Comment: This works for me after restarting the browser

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and found [this solution](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/08/change-googles-search-domain-in-google.html). Note that I didn't use the "better trick" that was posted in July 2013 (it didn't work for me with OS X and Chrome 29.0.1547.65); I'm using the older method, to wit:

1. Close all Chrome windows.
2. Go to Chrome's user profile directory (for example, in Windows Vista and Windows 7 the path is: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\`. Under OS X, it's `$USERHOME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/`.
3. In the Default directory, open the file Preferences in a text editor like vim or Notepad.
4. Find the two lines that include `last_known_google_url` and `last_prompted_google_url` and change the Google URL from `http://www.google.tld/` (where `.tld` is `.co.uk`, `.fr`, `.co.jp` etc.) to `http://www.google.com/` or any other Google domain.
5. Save the file and restart Chrome.
6. If you see an infobar that asks if you want to switch to your local domain or keep google.com, choose the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Wrench icon and select `Options`. In the `Basics` sections, click `Manage Search Engines` in the `Search` section.  In that section you can modify each of the query strings, so you can change it to just "google.com".

Comment: Actually I did that and also put google.com/ncr, none helps

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way, from Chrome help on the web:

Add a search engine: Scroll to the bottom of the dialog and fill out the following fields:

Add a new search engine: Enter a nickname for the search engine.

Keyword: Enter the text shortcut you want to use for the search engine. Use the keyword to do keyword searches.

URL: Enter the web address for the search engine -here you want to put:  http://www.google.com/search?q=%s